# How does Gradle ArtifactHandler works

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am learning Gradle, when I read the documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:artifacts(groovy.lang.Closure), it says the closure is delegated to `ArtifactHandler`, however, I can't figure out why:

```
configurations {
  //declaring new configuration that will be used to associate with artifacts
  schema
}

task schemaJar(type: Jar) {
  //some imaginary task that creates a jar artifact with the schema
}

//associating the task that produces the artifact with the configuration
artifacts {
  //configuration name and the task:
  schema schemaJar
}
```

especially:

```
schema schemaJar
```

How does Gradle (or Groovy) invoke this method:

```
PublishArtifact add(String configurationName, Object artifactNotation)
```

Comment: the "magic" is hidden in the default implementation class for `ArtifactHandler`, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/dependency-management/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/artifacts/dsl/DefaultArtifactHandler.java  : as lots of Gradle classes it uses dynamic method feature (see internal "DynamicMethods " class within `DefaultArtifactHandler` class )

Comment: you have a very similar example with ``dependencies{}` block where you can configure dependencies with `configurationName dependencyNotation1` syntax, and behind the hood it's calling method https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler:add(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks for the reply! So basically it is invoked by this class `private class DynamicMethods implements MethodAccess`

And this method `public DynamicInvokeResult tryInvokeMethod(String name, Object... arguments)`?

It check the input parameter, and call `pushArtifact` method?

Comment: short answer: yes. you can find more details in this Q/A on Gradle forum : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-understand-gradle-dependencies-block/24012

Comment: @M.Ricciuti thank you so much!